# manipulate StringBuilder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, substring, stringbuilder

I have a Note as stringBuilder with word and date: reval 41/50/50
I want to manipulate it, so I will have: reval 05/05/14.

(The date is only when I have the word reval before)

My function is:

```
Sub correctDateShowing(ByRef Note As StringBuilder)

    Dim index, i, j As Integer

    For index = 0 To Note.Length - 2
        If (Note(index).ToString = "r" And Note(index + 1).ToString = "e") Then
             For i = 6 To Note.Length - 1  'start from 6,because I want only the date to be reversed
                'Here I am Stuck!!
             Next   
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

I try to do some replacing with a tmp variable but it didn't work.
I will be glad to get some help.

Thanks All!!!

Comment: Let me make sure that I understand your request properly.  You have a `StringBuilder` that contains two substrings separated by a space and you want to reverse the second substring while leaving the first substring and the space in place.  Is that it?

Comment: Yes this is it, and then Note will contain the new stringBuilder

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to manipulate the text within the same `StringBuilder` rather than create a new one?  Isn't that the whole point of a `StringBuilder` in the first place?  If you're just going to create a new one then you may as well just use a `String`.  Also, how was this `StringBuilder` constructed in the first place?  It would be better to reverse the second substring before adding it if possible.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CorrectDateShowing(ByRef Note As StringBuilder)
    Dim str As String = Note.ToString()
    Dim arr As String() = str.Split(" "c)
    arr(1) = StrReverse(arr(1))
    Note = New StringBuilder(arr(0) & " " & arr(1))
End Sub
```

Split the text into two parts, reverse the second part (the date) and then reconnect them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim tempCharArray As char[]
Dim dateStartIndex, dateLength As int
'' Here you need to calculate the date start index and date length (i guess the date length is always 8)
Note.CopyTo(dateStartIndex, tempCharArray, 0, dateLength)
Note.Replace(new String(tempCharArray), new String(Array.Reverse(tempCharArray)), dateStartIndex, dateLength)
```

Comment: Hi, is this in vb?
I get error on tempCharArray: "Value of type char can not be converted to '1-dimensional array of char'

Comment: Sorry, It's been a while since my VB.Net days, I write c# most of the time now. change this "Dim tempCharArray As char[]" to this "Dim tempCharArray As char()" and it should work fine.

Comment: Also not good, on this: new String(Array.Reverse(tempCharArray)), 
I have an error: Expression does not produce a value.

But Thanks!